# Convert Hex string to Binary string, displaying all 4 bits of hex value

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Please help me with below case

I am trying to convert Hex string to Binary string with 1's and 0's. I tried below method. The problem I am facing here is, if the hex value is 0, the conversion is just 0 instead of "0000". I want the binary string to contain all the 4 bits of the hex value.

```
const string hexDataReadFromTag= "FF001"  
foreach (char c in hexDataReadFromTag.ToCharArray())
            {
                binaryData.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2));
}
```

output obtained is "11111111001" instead of "11111111000000000001"

Comment: Why do it character by character instead of just `Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexDataReadFromTag, 16), 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.PadLeft(4, '0')` to ensure each hexadecimal digit converts to 4 binary digits (`3` to `0011` and not `11`):

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')
```